# Firewall blocking SSH/SFTP connections. How to cheat it?

Tags: ssh, firewall, sftp, port-forwarding

Hi folks (sorry for the bad english)

I'm a college student, and I live in the student's house of my university.

I study computer science, and there we have the right to a space in a nfs server to store some files. This server assembles folders via an LDAP authentication in an ssh/sftp server that has external access, that is, I can access my stuff out of unviversity by a terminal or at Nautilus (using sftp).

Anyway, the only problem is that the network managers that control the student's house network blocked in firewall the port to ssh/sftp (22, I believe), and I just cannot access my files from the house. I have sent a few emails requesting the release of the port for this purpose. But always they say they will forward my request, lalalala spade and nothing happens, everything ends in feijoada. (kidding)

I'm Debian user for already some time (3 years :D) and I have this question for you guys: what alternatives I have to circumvent this lock?
Pointing out that:
1. I dont have another internet acess point to create a VPN;
2. I have no money to pay a third-party VPN (i'm a student, lol)
3. It's been so long that this disregard occurs, causing problems to my graduation, that I already want to break the blockade to play Dota 2 xD ( I need to relax too :) )

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Can you get someone in the CS faculty to run an ssh server on port 80 or port 443 for you?  If so, you could connect via that.

Port 80 may be blocked or transparently proxied by your college gateway, but port 443 probably won't be (as that would interfere with https connections to banks or whatever)